# AttributeError: 'HTMLSession' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: javascript, python, automation, python-requests, python-requests-html

Hello I am getting into requests_html and trying to render Javascript though it does not seem to process correctly. Very simple script, I added a sleep to see if it would render though still the same issue, here is the code.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

requests = HTMLSession()

requests.get('https://google.com')
requests.html.render(sleep=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's how it works, I can only get it it work when I save the response to a varaible:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

requests = HTMLSession()

resp = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
resp.html.render(sleep=2)

print(resp.text)
```